# SVN Change the HEAD to a particular revision and the set HEAD back to top

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I came across many posts where it showed ways to revert the changes of a commit in the working copy and commit again. But is there a way to do the following.

Supposed I have the following versions.

```
103 -> HEAD
102
```

I want to make it to

```
103 
102 -> HEAD
```

Do some tasks and then change it back.

```
103 -> HEAD
102
```

Is there a way to do it without making a version `104`?

Answer (score 1):

No, a regular user can't perform such operation. Revisions in Subversion are immutable.

The process of undoing changes made in commits is described in [SVNBook | Undoing changes](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo) and [TortoiseSVN Manual | Undoind changes](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-qs-guide.html#tsvn-qs-revert).

PS It looks like you are trying to solve some problem in an awkward way. Describe the problem in details and ask for advise in a separate question. Don't forget to read the documentation *before* asking questions.